# Как ООП влияет на скорость и объем используемой памяти при работе с большими объемами данных?

Tags: ооп, c++

Допустим, мне нужно оперировать данными о некоторых объектах (о центре масс, плотности, скорости и прочих параметрах). Не используя ООП я могу описать объект с помощью структуры, потом создать большой массив структур и перелопачивать его в процессе работы. Используя ООП я описываю класс объекта, создаю вектор таких классов и работаю с каждым экземпляром класса через его методы.

Насколько второй способ будет более затратен по ресурсам, если объектов очень много. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Основное различие будет в том, что структуры в памяти будут сохраняться в стек, а инстансы классов - в кучу, и доступ к классам будет как минимум медленней. Если у вас действительно огромные данные, то нужно смотреть в сторону структур и значимых типов вообще, но в большинстве случаев будет достаточно классов.

Comment: @Fike, причём здесь стек или не стек? В любую доступную память можно класть всё что заблагорассудится.

Comment: >Основное различие будет в том, что структуры в памяти будут сохраняться в стек, а инстансы классов - в кучу

в плюсах никто не гарантирует, что структуры будут храниться в стеке, а классы в куче, это не C#. Отличия там вообще довольно косметические

Comment: @DreamChild: да и в C# [тоже](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

Comment: Попутал с шарпом, простите.

Comment: >да и в C# тоже.

@VladD ну речь о том, что в отличие от плюсов в шарпе программист может быть уверенным, что вот эта переменная будет размещена в стеке, а вот та - в куче.

Comment: @DreamChild: насколько я понял статью по ссылке, компилятор имеет полное право перебросить переменную куда ему заблагорассудится, лишь бы семантика копирования и равенства сохранялась. (То, что текущие версии компилятора вообще пользуются системными стеком и кучей — интересная деталь реализации, не более.)

Comment: @DreamChild: Кроме того, вот вам простой пример: будет ли `x` размещена в стеке?

    struct S { public int x; }

Ответ: может, да, а может нет. В случае

    class C { public S s; }

будет вместе со всем классом в куче. И в этом случае тоже:

    object o = new S();

Даже если мы вроде бы явно располагаем переменную в стеке:

    object test()
    {
        S s = new S();

— последующий код может «загнать» её в кучу:

        return (Func<S>)(() => s);
    }

Comment: @VladD я (каюсь, грешен) статью по ссылке не читал. Я тут просто припоминаю что-то из то ли Рихтера, то ли Скита, писавшего про распространенный миф о типах-значениях, которые, как многие ошибочно думают, всегда лежат в стеке, что, однако, далеко не всегда так

Comment: @VladD все эти замечательные примеры (в том числе и случай с замыканиями) - это как раз то самое, о чем я вам говорил из вычитанного у Рихтера (да, это был именно он), поэтому мы с вами, очевидно, говорим об одних и тех же вещах.

Comment: @DreamChild: Угу, Рихтер и правда велик.

---
В любом случае, в C++ отличий между классом и структурой практически нет.

Comment: @DreamChild стек, куча... ничего, что по настроению компилятор может все сразу в регистр загнать вместо стека? Это я к тому, что в 2015 году не стоит думать, что вы понимаете, какой код выдает тут компилятор - слишком много вариативности.

Comment: @gbg , плюс к вами сказанному еще и настройки оптимизатора на это все повлияют.

Answer (score 5):

Обработчик, выполняющий манипуляции с данными структуры в обоих случаях идентичный:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

// в свободную функцию явно передается указатель на экземпляр структуры
void do_something(foo* thiz) {
    thiz->a = thiz->b * 2;
}


struct bar {
    int a;
    int b;

    // в функцию-член неявно передается указатель на экземпляр структуры (this)
    void do_something(/* bar* this */) {
        this->a = this->b * 2;
    }
};
```

В случае с отдельной функцией вы явно передаете указатель на структуру, в случае функции-члена - это сделает компилятор. Таким образом здесь принципиальной разницы нет в быстродействии.

Единственные накладные расходы при хранении объекта (не важно структуры или класса) - это несколько байтов на экземпляр, в случае, если используются виртуальные методы (указатель на vtab).

Что касается использования массива или вектора (`std::vector`) для хранения данных, то вектор, никоим образом не замедляет доступ к элементам (если специально не использовать доступ с проверкой на выход за границы массива -  `std::vector::at`).

Comment: Добавлю: `vptr` — это указатель. Соответственно, «несколько байт» — это 4 на x32 и 8 на x64.

Comment: @Arhad верно, в том числе может быть и 2 байта, и вообще не нормировано, поэтому не стал уточнять.

Comment: Все же вряд ли вопрос о косметической разнице между `a.f()` (уже ООП?) и `f(&a)` (не ООП). Если смотреть на ООП как на парадигму, то она в первую очередь подвигает разработчика к проектированию неких обобщенных программ, что  (vector тут скорее исключение) почти всегда менее эффективно, чем программа, решающая конкретную задачу. В случае С++ эффективный (но создающий дополнительные проблемы на уровне компиляции) инструмент генерализации решений это templates (но относятся ли они к ООП?).

Comment: @avp ну если по тайтлу вопроса, то да, а по тексту вроде конкретные варианты - выносить обработку или включить в объект. Тем не менее, в большинстве случаев, используя c++ цена за ООП подход минимальна, либо вообще отсутствует. Другое дело некоторые универсальные решения, которые встречаются в стандартной библиотеке (хотя и таких очень мало, как правило все очень эффективно).

Comment: [Цена вопроса](http://250bpm.com/blog:8), кстати, там же интересна [предыдущая статья](http://250bpm.com/blog:4). Заметьте,  автор пишет о себе `I've been using C++ whole my professional career and it's still my language of choice when doing most projects.`

Comment: @avp да это каноничный c vs c++ срач стартер, но там на каждом шагу автор лукавит, начиная с первого же примера, где в list он пихает указатели а не сами объекты (как в варианте C).

Comment: Ну, по крайней мере в g++ с list уже лучше -- `  template<typename _Tp>
    struct _List_node : public __detail::_List_node_base
    {
      ///< User's data.
      _Tp _M_data; ... }` Однако, согласитесь, с данными, которые одновременно могут быть в нескольких списках (или которые без копирования должны кочевать из одного списка в другой) так обойтись не получится.

Comment: В таком случае и в варианте C придется держать указатели на них. Т.е. разницы опять нет никакой.

Comment: Можно и без этого. См., например: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h (и примерно то же: http://pastebin.com/TGdUA9Se)

Answer (score 2):

Всё всегда зависит от контекста/ситуации. Если то что ТС называет "объектом" не имеет собственного "поведения" или "внутренних процессов" или "событий" (а просто как "блок данных") и предполагается иметь массив этих "объектов", то описывать классом нет смысла, будет лучше записью.
В иных условиях вполне может оказаться эффективнее сделать класс и иметь массив ссылок. Так что однозначного ответа быть не может. Если бы он был - вещь которая "хуже" просто бы давно исчезла.

Comment: В одном языке называется "запись", в другом "структура", в третьем "блок", а по факту это одно и то же. Так какая разница?

Answer (score 1):

Операции с выделением, перевыделением памяти достаточно медленные и поэтому для оптимизации их лучше избегать.
 На мой взгляд грамотнее выделить память под массив записей (структур) и передавать ссылку на запись (структуру) в объект для обработки. Это тоже будет ООП. Смысл создавать 1000 экземпляров объектов я не вижу.

Все на самом деле просто тестируется.. Достаточно создать прототип объекта и выделить память под 1 миллион объектов и посмотреть продолжительность их создания и объем выделенной памяти. Тесты будут красноречивее любой теории. Возможно, компиляторы очень круто все сами оптимизируют, возможно, этого  не случится. На саму математику вызов из метода или процедуры думаю значительно не повлияет.

Answer (score 0):

Если учесть что у каждого объекта есть указатель this, а также указатель на имя класса и указатель на список всех функций класса то в остальном расходы по сравнению со структурой минимальны, самый простой способ это просмотреть это сделать дезасемблирование и увидеть получившийся код, так же можно указать оптимизацию по данным, а не по скорости для компилятора.

Comment: Это может быть доход а не расход) инструкция короче. Вообще я уже смирился с колебаниями в 5%, невозможно предсказать как поведет себя компилятор, он у меня недавно сподкнулся об `for(i=n;--i..` и `for(i=0;i++..` из-за моих "оптимизаций" все замедлялось на 1%, в итоге решил что из-за этого компилер пошел не в ту степь (сама эта короткая процедура в самом деле ускорилась)

Comment: Откуда информация, что объект хранит указатель на себя (this) и список всеx функций?

Comment: Указатель `this` *не хранится* внутри класса, *а формируется* при передаче указателя на экземпляр класса в метод этого самого класса.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае Вам надо обдумать требуемые алгоритмы и исходя из этого выбирать между несколькими массивами и массивом структур/классов. Основные потери скорости будут не от самого ООП, а от организации данных в памяти и соответственно кэширования данных в процессе работы. Например, для вычисления средней скорости лучше использовать раздельные массивы для данных, а для вычисления энергии тела по массе-скорости-температуре - массивы структур

Answer (score -1):

ООП никак не влияет на скорость и объем используемой памяти.

Comment: Сильное утверждение.

Comment: @avp я бы сказал, что ложное

Comment: @DreamChild, извольте сказать, почему ложное (-:

Comment: @gkuznets пардон, моя ошибка. Хотел сказать про таблицу виртуальных функций, необходимую для реализации позднего связывания, однако затем вспомнил, что у структур тоже могут быть виртуальные методы

Comment: Емаё, ООП -- это некий абстрактный подход к программированию, парадигма (что бы это не значило). Можно писать в объектном стиле и ни разу не использовать плюсовые классы, наследование, виртуальность и прочие деструкторы. Посмотрите на линуксовое API для файловых систем -- ООП на чистом Си.

Comment: @gkuznets, давайте, пожалуйста, без "ёмаюкающих" лекций - я не школьник, и вполне знаком с сабжем. Речь о том, что в данном контексте (как и в 99% других контекстов) под ооп подразумевается не абстрактная парадигма, которую кто-то даже реализует "из фольги и желудей", а конкретная ее реализация в языке С++ - именно с конструкторами-деструкторами, виртуальными функциями, наследованием и прочими атрибутами. Ведь автор вопроса спрашивал именно об этом, а не о той абстракции, что вы упоминаете.